# add filter to table using laravel and livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm trying to create a filter using laravel and livewire. My filter will have a selectbox with this items:

- show all
- show active item
- show inactive item

i want when user select active from selectbox, i want the items that are active to be displayed.
I wrote the code like this but it doesn't work! what is the problem?

```php
public $filter_buy_status = '';

public function render()
{
    if ($this->loadData == true) {
        $coins = Coin::where('name', 'like', '%'.$this->search.'%')
            ->orWhere('symbol', 'like', '%'.$this->search.'%')
            ->where('buy_status' , $this->filter_buy_status)
            ->get();
    } else {
        $coins = [];
    }
    return view('livewire.backend.crypto.coins')->with('coins' , collect($coins)->paginate($this->perPage));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you haven't shown your select-element, let's assume that it looks something like this, where "show all" is an empty value.

```html
<select wire:model="filter_buy_status">
    <option value="">Show All</option>
    <option value="active">Show Active</option>
    <option value="inactive">Show Inactive</option>
</select>
```

Then, because an empty string is a "falsy" value (meaning that if you do `if ("")` it will be false), we can apply the condition using `when()`. This is a Laravel filter method that is only applied when the condition in `when()` is true.

Its also important to group your `WHERE` conditions. If you want the filter of status to be applied to all, and then search "where symbol OR where name", then your SQL would look like this

```sql
WHERE buy_status = 'Active' AND (name LIKE '%search%' OR symbol LIKE '%search%')
```

In Laravel, that means that you group all the `orWhere()` in a grouped `where()`, like this

```php
$coins = Coin::where(function($query) {
    return $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$this->search.'%')
        ->orWhere('symbol', 'like', '%'.$this->search.'%');
    })
    ->when($this->filter_buy_status, function($query, $status) {
        return $query->where('buy_status' , $this->filter_buy_status);
    })
    ->get();
```